# Understanding definition of big-O notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

In a textbook, I came across a definition of big-oh notation, it goes as follows:

We say that $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ if there are constants $C$ and $k$ such that $$|f(x)| \le C|g(x)|$$ whenever $x \gt k$.

If I'm not mistaken, this basically translates to: $$f(x) = O(g(x)) \Leftarrow\Rightarrow (\exists C,\exists k|C,k \epsilon \Bbb R \land (x \gt k \rightarrow |f(x)| \le C|g(x)|))$$
Now, I have two questions regarding this statement:

1. Is my verbose translation correct?
2. What exactly does this definition of big-oh notation mean about the usage of big-oh notation, because from what I understand through computer science, big-oh is used to represent the computational complexity of an algorithm. So how does this relate to the complexity of an algorithm (if at all)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your translation is correct. The intuition behind big-oh notation is that $f$ is $O(g)$ if $g(x)$ grows as fast or faster than $f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. This is used in computer science whenever studying the time complexity of an algorithm. Specifically, if we let $f(n)$ be the run-time (number of steps) that an algorithm takes on an $n$ bit input to give an output, then it may be useful to say something like $f$ is $O(n^2)$, so we know that the algorithm is relatively fast for large inputs $n$. On the other hand, if all we knew was $f$ is $O(2^n)$, then $f$ might run too slowly for large inputs.

Note I say "might" here, because big-oh only gives you an upper bound, so $n^2$ is $O(2^n)$ but $2^n$ is not $O(n^2)$.

Comment: To extend on the "might" part at the end: big-omega exists for lower bounds, and big-theta is used to introduce a tighter bound. Oftentimes, people will say "big-oh" when they actually mean "big-theta"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your verbose translation is correct.

The definition essentially indicates that Big-Oh notation is a tool to denote an upper bound for a function.  That is, if $f(x)$ is $\mathcal{O}(2^x)$, that means that, beyond some point, a constant multiple of $2^x$ will always be bigger than $f(x)$.

This is used in computer science to indicate that, in the long run, we can just assume it takes $2^x$ operations to perform the algorithm (because it's close enough).