# Taylor Series Expansion in characteristic function

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

How can we expand the following equation in Taylor series?

$\frac{1}{2}$e$^{iu/\sqrt{n}}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$e$^{-iu/\sqrt{n}}$

The solution is 1 $-$ $\frac{u^2}{2n}$ + O($\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$), but I do not quite understand how it is obtained.

The last step is to take the limit of  (1 $-$ $\frac{u^2}{2n}$ + O($\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$))$^{nt}$ when n goes to infinite,  how can we obtain the limit as e$^{-\frac{u^2}{2n}nt}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me answer your first question, regarding finding the Taylor expansion:

Recall $$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}.$$ Taking $x=u/\sqrt{n}$ gives that your function is $\cos (u/\sqrt{n}).$ Now, just use the standard Taylor expansion for $\cos x.$

Now, let me answer your last question, regarding the steps in a solution that you've seen:

Remember that $$e^x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n.$$ You can use this and appropriate variable substitutions to get the result that you want.

Comment: Thanks! How can I have the equation of cos x as you mentioned?  I mean the first equation.

Comment: Do you mean where does it come from? If so, it comes from Euler's formula: $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x.$

Comment: ohh, sorry, I made an error, it is should be iu/ $\sqrt{n}$.  Then what does the big O mean?  which course material will cover big O?

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly! As for big O notation, here's a link that you might like: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620145/understanding-definition-of-big-o-notation

Comment: It, effectively, presents an upper bound on a function by another function. When used in Taylor series, the big O stores the information of all of the rest of the term with one term which bounds the rest as you take the limit.