# Can someone explain what does log n in $O(\log n)$ mean? I want a deeper explanation.

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics

When I ask this question I'm usually given the response that when you see $O(\log  n)$ that means the problem is continually halved.

I want to understand why is this case? Maybe add some explanations of the properties of the logarithm and how it relates to algorithms and asymptotics.

Comment: When the problem size doubles, the algorithm approximately increases by a constant time. That's just how logs work.

Comment: $\log n$ in this context means exactly the same thing as it does in every other context: it is the logarithm of $n$ (the natural logarithm, although the base ends up not mattering). I think the real question here is "what does big-$O$ notation mean?" There are few discussion about this already, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620145/understanding-definition-of-big-o-notation

Comment: In complexity theory, it is often the binary logarithm we are interested in: if $n$ is a positive integer, $\log_2\,n$ is just 1 less than the number of digits in the binary expansion of $n$. A perfectly balanced binary tree with $n$ nodes has height $\log_2\,n + 1$.  $\log_2$ and $\log$ are related by a constant factor, so it doesn't matter which you use when you say $O(\log\,n)$.

Comment: If your question is still "what does $\log n$ mean" (i.e. you haven't seen logarithms before) you should learn about logarithms in a more general context, because they are widely useful in virtually every area of mathematics. I'd recommend this Khan Academy page to get started: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:logs

Comment: Strictly speaking, it means the ratio $\biggl|\dfrac{f(n)}{\log n}\biggr|$ is bounded.

Comment: Note first that the classes $O(\log(n))$ and $O(\log_2(n))$ are the same, since $\log(n)=\frac{1}{\log_2(e)}\log_2(n)$ differ by a constant. Halving is not the only way to get logarithmic growth of the number of steps, but it is one example of it. If an algorithm reduces at each step to the same problem with half the size of the input, then the input size $I_k$ in the $k$-th iteration satisfies $I_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}I_k$. This recurrence has the solution $I_k=\frac{I_0}{2^k}$. The algorithm terminates when $I_k$ is small, say smaller than $1$. So, $I_0/2^k<1$ gives that $k>\log_2(I_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logarithm has this property

$$\log(a^k)=k\log(a)$$
$$\log(a^{k+1})=\log(a)+k\log(a)$$

This means for $O(\log(n))$ that if you multiply the size of input for an algorithm by any constant $a$, the function will need $\log(a)$ more time (or some other resource) to execute.

If your array is three times longer, the algorithm will need $\log(3)$ more time to execute at worst.

(Notice that we are not talking about a time unit here, is it minute, hour, day, but it is a fixed unit we use. This depends on the actual hardware where an algorithm executes, but for one and the same environment it is a fixed unit.)

The same goes for space that an algorithm might need, or any other resource.